# Getting text from QLineEdit to append to QTextEdit upon QLineEdit returnpressed()

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write a simple Qt program which takes text inside a QLineEdit and appends it into a QTextEdit object when the return key is pressed.

Here is the code for my program:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>

#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTextEdit textArea;
    textArea.setReadOnly(true);

    QLineEdit lineEdit;

    QPushButton quit("Quit");
    QObject::connect(&quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    QHBoxLayout hLayout;
    hLayout.addWidget(&lineEdit);
    hLayout.addWidget(&quit);

    QVBoxLayout vLayout;
    vLayout.addWidget(&textArea);
    vLayout.addLayout(&hLayout);

    QWidget window;
    window.setBaseSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    window.setLayout(&vLayout);
    window.show();

    //This is the line I can not get to work
    QObject::connect(&lineEdit, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), &textArea, SLOT(append(lineEdit.text())));

    return app.exec();

}
```

Essentially, the problem is connecting the QLineEdit returnPressed() SIGNAL to the QTextEdit append() SLOT. I am hoping someone can point out what is wrong with my code.

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your program, you should notice on the console the following Qt error output..

```
Object::connect: No such slot QTextEdit::append(lineEdit.text()) in ..
```

You would need to qualify the `append` reference in your call to `connect` with the `QTextEdit` variable name `textArea`.

But that's not going to help much because you can only specify signal and slot method names and parameter types when calling `connect` so you can't specify `lineEdit.text()` in there.

Since the `append()` slot expects a `QString`, ideally you would want to connect a signal that includes a `QString` but there is no such signal for `QLineEdit`s.

You pretty much have to write a slot yourself that you can connect to `returnPressed()` and call `textArea.append(lineEdit.text())` from there. You will need to subclass a `QObject` of some kind to write a slot which would usually mean subclassing `QWidget` and putting all of your UI building code in its constructor.

You might also notice that your program crashes when you close it. Since Qt likes to manage the destruction of most `QObject`s itself, it is usually best to allocate all `QObject` instances on the heap with `new`. This isn't technically necessary all the time but it is much easier :)

Comment: Sorry if this sounds excessively n00bish but how do I define my own slot function? I tried simply void slotFunction(QLineEdit *lineEdit, QTextEdit *textArea){textArea->append(lineEdit->text());} and then calling that but I still get the Object::connect error. Thanks in advance, you've been a tremendous help (huge thanks for explaining why my program happened to be crashing btw :) )

Comment: There is a actually a lot of detail to cover to explain that but the short version is: Your slot function doesn't need parameters since returnPressed() doesn't have any. Declare a method in a QObject subclass and be sure to have `public slots:` before it. Example code here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Here's an updated version of my code I wrote following your advice: http://pastie.org/private/buz9zfrml6krmkiothupq . I'm getting a linker error : "C:\projects\qt\Assignment1-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\Assignment1\main.cpp:14: error: undefined reference to `vtable for Assignment1'". Any way you can give me some guidance on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learning C++ and Qt at the same time is quite a lot to bite off at once :) It isn't enough to just declare the methods, they need an implementation too which would mean putting the code for that `QObject` subclass in a `.h` and `.cpp` file. It would be better to subclass `QWidget` and use that as your main window with all the relevant code in it. A direct `QObject` subclass like that is a bit awkward.

Comment: Ah, alright I understand what you mean now. I broke everything up into  a nice beautiful QObject inherited class and I got it working. Thank you very, very, very much. Here's my final, working code: http://pastie.org/private/7y8nno15rtsbla5uanzf7g . PS: I actually do know C++ quite well but I've got a homework assignment based on Qt due within 30 minutes and I only started Qt for the first time less than an hour ago hehe ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
QObject::connect(&lineEdit, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), &textArea, SLOT(append(lineEdit.text())));
```

returnPressed() doesn't take any arguments, but append(QString) does take one argument; a QString. Thus, if this would work, you would theoretically call append(""), meaning you wouldn't append anything. Using lineEdit.text() wouldn't work either at this place.

I would recommend you to create a class for the widget:

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget(QWidget parent = 0);
    //Other public functions
private:
    //Private functions and variables
public slots:
    void boom();
};
```

Then you can just use
    Widget w(0);
    w.show();
in your main function.

void boom() would be called by returnPressed(), and it would take lineEdit.text() and append it to the QTextEdit.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code it might be helpful.....

```
 #include "hwidget.h"

Hwidget::Hwidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

}

void Hwidget::mainform_init(void)
{
    lineeditp = new QLineEdit;
    quitp = new QPushButton("&Exit");

    hboxlayoutp = new QHBoxLayout;
    hboxlayoutp->addWidget(lineeditp);
    hboxlayoutp->addWidget(quitp,0,0);

    vboxlayoutp = new QVBoxLayout;
    texteditp = new QTextEdit;
    texteditp->setReadOnly(true);
    vboxlayoutp->addWidget(texteditp,0,0);
    vboxlayoutp->addLayout(hboxlayoutp);

    QWidget *mywin = new QWidget;
    mywin->setLayout(vboxlayoutp);
    mywin->setWindowTitle("My Sig and Slot");
    mywin->show();
    lineeditp->setFocus();
}

void Hwidget::mcopy(void)
{
    qDebug() <<"i am your copy slot";

    texteditp->setText(lineeditp->text());
   lineeditp->clear();

}

#include <QApplication>

#include "hwidget.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    Hwidget *hwin = new Hwidget;

  hwin->mainform_init();
  hwin->connect(hwin->quitp,SIGNAL(pressed()),
               qApp,SLOT(quit()));

  hwin->connect(hwin->lineeditp,SIGNAL(returnPressed()),
               hwin,SLOT(mcopy()));

    return app.exec();
    return 0;
}
#ifndef HWIDGET_H
#define HWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>


class Hwidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Hwidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void mainform_init(void);

signals:

public slots:
    void mcopy(void);

private:


   QHBoxLayout *hboxlayoutp;
   QVBoxLayout *vboxlayoutp;
public:
   QPushButton *quitp;
    QLineEdit *lineeditp;
     QTextEdit *texteditp;

};

#endif // HWIDGET_H
```